# Is there a way to append a callback to an each statement?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I have a group of five elements, that when clicked: disappear in sequential order, load a new background image pertinent to which element is clicked AND then crossfades to the new background.

I am trying to inject new content once the new background is loaded via ajax. The problem is it's looping through ALL 5 elements and firing the function 4 other times, as opposed the one element that is clicked.

```
<script>

    $('.actor-img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

            // First remove a 'selected' class from all elements with this class name
         $('.actor-img').removeClass('selected');

            // Add 'selected' class to the one that was clicked
        $(this).addClass('selected');

            // Loop thru all the elements w/ this class name
            // The variable 'v' will represent the actual element in each loop
        $('.actor-img').each(function(i,v) {

                // If this element doesn't have 'selected' class, hide it
             if(!$(v).hasClass('selected')) {

                    // hide it!
                    $(v).hide();

                    // or, to fade out, comment out the above and uncomment below
                     $(v).fadeOut('slow',function(){$('.page-section').load('tail_one_frame_one.html');});

                 var paras = $('.actor-img'),
                         i = 0;

                    // If using jQuery 1.4, you don't need to do || [].
                     (function() {
                      $(paras[i++] || []).fadeOut('slow', arguments.callee);
                     })();



                // This item IS selected, so change the background accordingly 
                 } else {

                    // the NEW bg class was stored in the div as data-bg
                    // get it, and save as newClassName
                    var newClassName = $(v).attr('data-bg');

                    // First reset to just .page-section-img
                    // Then add the new class (to change the background)
                 $('.page-section-img').attr('class','page-section-img').addClass(newClassName);

                 }


             });

     });

</script>
```

Comment: When do you want the callback to happen? (keep in mind, the each itself will be done near immediately)\

Comment: @Kevin B we are running animations and we want it happen after the final animation is finished.

Comment: `$(".actor-img").promise().done(function(){alert("Hello World!");});` should do it. It would go after the each. After all actor-img elements are done animating, the alert will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following recursive function.

Hope that helps.

```
var elements = $('.actor-img');
elementIndex = 0;

fadeElements(elements[elementIndex]);

var fadeElements = function(element) {
    $(element).fadeOut('slow', function() { 
        if (elementIndex++ < elements.length - 1) {           
            fadeElements(elements[elementIndex]; 
        }
    });
};
```